# Telegram bot получение текста после нажатия на inline keyboard

Tags: java, telegram-bot, telegram

Разрабатываю Телеграм бота на Java. Имеется кнопка "Send feedback", представляющая собой InlineKeyboardMarkup.
При нажатии на неё бот ожидает ввода и отправки сообщения пользователем.
(т.е. отправляется новое сообщение с префиксом "/send-feedback " + то что ввёл пользователь) и только я получаю сообщение в своём чате.

Однако, если первый пользователь нажал на FEEDBACK, но ещё не ввёл сообщение, а второй пользователь вызвал любую другую команду, то второй пользователь и отправит этот фидбек с командой, которую вызвал, текстом, а человек который реально нажал его отправить, введёт текст, нажмёт отправить  и ему выдаст, что такой команды не существует. Я понимаю, что возможно дело в переменной "prefix", но я не знаю как архитектурно верно сделать многопользовательский ввод, чтобы юзеры не перехватывали команды друг друга и было грамотно.
Текущее решение:

```
 // добавил поле
 private String prefix = "";

 if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText()) {
        // здесь добавляю префикс к сообщению
        String messageText = prefix + update.getMessage().getText();
        long chatId = update.getMessage().getChatId();
    
    // 2. Прилетело сюда
    if (messageText.startsWith("/send-feedback")) {
            String feedback = messageText.substring(messageText.indexOf(" ") + 1);
            new Thread(() -> sendFeedback(chatId, feedback)).start();
 //...

 } else if (update.hasCallbackQuery()) {
        String callbackData = update.getCallbackQuery().getData();
        chatIdCallback = update.getCallbackQuery().getMessage().getChatId();          

        switch (callbackData) {
            // 1. Нажатие на кнопку
            case "FEEDBACK" -> {
                prefix = "/send-feedback ";
                // возможность отмены ввода и отправка сообщения
                cancelButton(chatIdCallback);
            }

            // Отмена ввода
            case "CANCEL" -> {
                prefix = "";                   
            }

    // Отмена ввода
    private void cancelButton(long chatId) {
      SendMessage message = prepareMessage(chatId, "Отменить");        

      Map<String, String> buttons = new LinkedHashMap<>();
      buttons.put("CANCEL", cancelButtonText);

      message.setReplyMarkup(InlineKeyboards.inlineKeyboardMaker(buttons));
      executeMessage(message);
    }
```

Всё работает корректно пока второй пользователь не встрянет между нажатием  кнопки и вводом текста первым пользователем.

Как грамотно реализовать сценарий:

1. юзер нажал кнопку клавиатуры "Send feedback"
2. ввёл текст отзыва
3. нажал отправить сообщение
4. сообщение ушло админу

И все эти операции должны быть единым целым. Может как-то потоками реализовать, но не знаю как. Да - неужели у самого бота нет такого функционала!

Весь код здесь
https://github.com/mrprogre/avandy-news-bot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Создайте класс, который будет хранить состояние для каждого
   пользователя. Например, UserState:

   ```
   public class UserState {
       private String currentState;
       private String feedbackMessage;

       // Конструкторы, геттеры, сеттеры
   }
   ```
2. Вместо использования глобальной переменной, используйте Map, чтобы
   связать идентификатор пользователя с его состоянием. Для примера:

   ```
   private Map<Long, UserState> userStates = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
   ```

   Теперь у каждого пользователя может быть свой набор данных, а не
   общий prefix
3. Доработайте обработчики сообщений и колбэков так, чтобы они
   проверяли и обновляли состояние пользователя, используя этот Map:

   ```
   if (update.hasCallbackQuery()) {
       long userId = update.getCallbackQuery().getFrom().getId();
       String callbackData = update.getCallbackQuery().getData();

       switch (callbackData) {
           case "FEEDBACK" -> {
               UserState userState = userStates.computeIfAbsent(userId, UserState::new);
               userState.setCurrentState("AWAITING_FEEDBACK");
               // Отобразить пользователю, что он должен ввести отзыв
           }
           // Другие случаи...
       }
   }
   ```
4. Обрабатывайте текстовые сообщения в контексте состояния
   пользователя:

   ```
   if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText()) {
       long userId = update.getMessage().getFrom().getId();
       String messageText = update.getMessage().getText();
       UserState userState = userStates.get(userId);

       if (userState != null && "AWAITING_FEEDBACK".equals(userState.getCurrentState())) {
           // Пользователь отправил отзыв
           userState.setFeedbackMessage(messageText);
           userState.setCurrentState("FEEDBACK_RECEIVED");
           // Отправить отзыв админу
           sendFeedback(userId, messageText);
       } else {
           // Обработка других текстовых сообщений
       }
   }
   ```
5. Как только отзыв будет обработан, измените состояние пользователя
   обратно, чтобы он мог интерактировать с ботом далее:

   ```
   userState.setCurrentState(null); // или другое состояние
   ```

   Таким образом, вы сможете отслеживать отдельно поведение каждого
   пользователя

Comment: Да, я примерно так и планировал, но решил, что это будет ещё более жёсткий "велосипед" и что наверное у Telegram есть какая-нибудь фича на этот счёт. Сейчас реализовал Ваше решение - супер! Сделал немного по другому, у меня посложнее функционал, но основные моменты применил Ваши. Спасибо за столь подробное описание!

Comment: 5. пункт сделал как `userStates.remove(chatId)`чтобы пропустить шаг присваивания нового статуса. Просто удаляю запись. А в классе **UserState** создал только поле **state**